# Qtip do not show icon?

Tags: jquery, html, css, qtip

**Hi,**

Pleas take look at this example : http://jsfiddle.net/snowman/Hne3h/1/

If you hover over the questionmark you will get a qtip, the problem is that the question icon that is placed in the tooltip is not shown?

**Any advice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your CSS Specificity: `.tooltip .content .icon`
try this instead:

```
.content .icon
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/CCGCw/).

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is not matching once qTip has modified the HTML.

Try removing the `.tooltip` prefix.

[Works on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Hne3h/2/).

Comment: I don't see icon in Firefox 3.6 either Chrome 9.

Comment: @Voldy: It does appear on FF 3.6.15

Comment: @ifaour: Icon inside a tooltip?

Comment: hmm? I have tried this in FireFox 3.6.15 and IE 8.0.7600, both do not show the questionmark WITHIN the TOOLTIP?

Comment: @Voldy: Thanks for the heads-up! I've re-read the question and posted an answer too!

Comment: @SnowJim See update, and I also see @ifaour has figured it out too! :)